# Qual a forma mais completa de instalar python no Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, instalador

Sei que essa pergunta pode ser interpretada como uma discussão, por isso a fiz com a palavra "completa" ao invés de "melhor".

Sou usuário python no GNU/Linux e aqui ele vem mais ou menos pré-instalado. Ainda assim, posso usar o pip pra instalar ou remover novos pacotes, criando uma instalação completa para o meu uso cotidiano (virtualenv, pacotes de computação científica e outras bibliotecas de desenvolvimento, tipo tkinter).

Tenho visto muitas perguntas de python no Windows (no SOEN tem muitas, começam a aparecer algumas aqui no SOPT), e sei que existe uma versão de python (tanto a 2.7 quanto a 3.x) para instalação a partir do site da própria linguagem, bem como alguns pacotes para [computação científica](http://www.python.org/download/windows/).

Imagino que a resposta vá depender da minha aplicação. Considerando dois ambientes distintos:

- Computação Científica (nesse caso, qual das duas aplicações listadas no link acima é a mais completa?)
- Ambiente de Desenvolvimento comercial (aqui, não tenho nem idéia)

Que tipo de ferramentas existem para MS Windows que permitam que eu tenha um bom ambiente de desenvolvimento em python, de forma simples, rápida e completa?

E ainda, existe algo equivalente ao PIP para Windows?

Comment: No final das contas você quer ter um gerenciador de pacotes python no windows, sendo ele o pip ou não, certo? Pergunto porque *"Que tipo de ferramentas existem para MS Windows que permitam que eu tenha um bom ambiente de desenvolvimento, de forma simples, rápida e completa?"* ficou bem genérico (e difícil de responder).

Comment: @talles, preciso mesmo aprender a fazer perguntas aqui... =P Vou tentar reeditar a pergunta.

Comment: @talles, editado.

Comment: Não entendo, você perguntou "Qual a forma mais completa de instalar python no Windows?" e depois "Que tipo de ferramentas existem para MS Windows que permitam que eu tenha um bom ambiente de desenvolvimento em python, de forma simples, rápida e completa?" e ainda "existe algo equivalente ao PIP para Windows?", você basicamente fez 3 perguntas diferentes.

Comment: Quando você está no Linux por exemplo, você geralmente já tem o Python instalado por padrão, 2.7.x e 3.x, no seu caso, você disse que utiliza bibliotecas para computação científica, então você acessa o gerenciador de pacotes e instala os pacotes de relacionados a computação cientifica. No Windows você irá fazer basicamente a mesma coisa. Baixe a versão desejada do Python no site oficial, e instale o PIP para instalar os pacotes desejados que estejam no PyPI, o PIP é multi-plataforma de acordo com o que está escrito no site deles, caso o pacote não esteja no PyPI você terá que inst. manualmente

Comment: @Zignd, sim, são três perguntas. Mas se reparares bem, a pergunta do título é repetida uma vez na descrição da pergunta, uma vez que detalho o que desejo (ambiente para computação científica e ambiente de produção comercial), e o pip é um bonus. Aliás, obrigado pela dica do pip.

Comment: Mero comentário mesmo: fiz exatamente o inverso aqui, baixei a PyQt4 e o Py 3 mais recente e só pus nas pastas sem install (na verdade instalei numa VM "descartável" e só copiei as pastas pro OS definitivo). Funcionou que é uma beleza (a intenção ja era usar libs pré-compiladas mesmo), eu só tive que associar as extensões .py e .pyw ao .exe do Py no meu editor de código pra testar "a toque de tecla".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Uma das maiores dificuldade em se instalar pacotes Python no Windows é que nem sempre os recursos necessários para **compilá-los a partir dos fontes** estão presentes. Isso causa problemas ao instalar certos pacotes via PIP, de modo que alguma intervenção manual acaba sendo necessária.

Pela minha experiência pessoal (Python 2.7 no Windows XP), os passos para a configuração de um ambiente Python seriam:

1. Instalar o próprio Python, do seu [site oficial](https://www.python.org/downloads/);
2. Instalar o **setuptools**, a partir de um [binário próprio para Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools);
3. Instalar o **pip**, a partir de um [binário próprio para Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip);
4. Colocar a pasta onde está o pip (ex.: `C:\Python27\Scripts`) no `PATH` (opcional);
5. Para cada pacote que você quiser instalar:

   1. Tentar instalar pelo pip: `pip install pacote`.
   2. Se der erro na instalação, procurar um binário próprio para Windows no Google.

Infelizmente, pela minha experiência pessoal posso dizer que esse passo 5.2 é mais frequente do que eu gostaria... Pacotes "python puro" como o Django costumam instalar bem através do pip, mas aqueles que requerem uma interface nativa (em geral via C) costumam falhar com frequência.

Quanto a encontrar binários, em geral simplesmente busco no Google, mas [nesse site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) tem uma lista bem extensa de binários tanto pra Windows 32bits quanto pra 64bits. Alguns dos pacotes que precisei para desenvolvimento comercial (ex.: ReportLab - geração de PDF, psycopg2 - interface com o Postgres, mod-wsgi - interface com o Apache, etc) bem como alguns de computação científica (NumPy, SciPy, PyEphem etc) e muitos outros estão disponíveis nessa lista.

Comment: quanto aos pacotes que precisam de C/C++, não seria o caso de ter um compilador C instalado no sistema?

Comment: @LuizAngioletti sim, mas não sei se seria o suficiente. Muitos pacotes têm dependencias **a mais** para se compilar a partir do fonte do que para simplesmente usar o pacote, por isso cada caso é um caso. A vantagem do pré-compilado é que alguém já teve pra você o trabalho de configurar tudo corretamente e - presume-se - confirmar que funciona bem no ambiente Windows. Mas se você tiver um compilador instalado, e o Python encontrá-lo corretamente, etc, creio que a instalação via pip vai funcionar sem problemas (ou: menos pacotes apresentarão problemas)

Comment: Além de tudo que o @mgibsonbr, acho que vale a pena acrescentar a instalação do virtualenv que, para o windows, é um pouco mais complicada.
Apesar de o virtualenv ser apenas necessário um `pip install virtualenv`, para instalar o wrapper é necessário mexer com o Power Shell, como pode ser visto [aqui](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html). Também acho interessante esse [tutorial](https://zignar.net/2012/06/17/install-python-on-windows/) como leitura complementar, principalmente por causa da parte bônus.

Answer (score 6):

Aconselho você a estudar um pouco sobre Vagrant ou alguma ferramenta que vai poder provisionar vários ambientes isolados do seu sistema operacional.

Você pode muito bem trabalhar no windows e o seu ambiente de trabalho ser provisionado por um ubuntu, por exemplo.

[www.vagrantup.com](http://www.vagrantup.com)

[www.docker.io](http://docker.io)

Comment: a ideia não é trabalhar dentro do Ubuntu, dentro do Windows. A questão é justamente como trabalhar independente do Ubuntu (ou Linux em geral), dentro do Windows. Vou olhar o Vagrant, mas sua resposta não atende à pergunta, por isso os eventuais downvotes.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no Vagrant e você vai ver que a resposta responde sua pergunta sim. ;) O Vagrant cria uma máquina virtual (praticamente invisível) e isola o seu sistema operacional do seu ambiente de desenvolvimento (teste, produção e etc). Então você estará livre para configurar sua máquina da mesma forma que fazia no Linux e trabalhar com ela no Windows. Tudo isso sem muito esforço.

Comment: +1 Apesar de não ser a solução desejada/esperada pelo OP, o Vagrant realmente responde a pergunta "como obter um ambiente Python completo no Windows", e é usada por alguns desenvolvedores.

Answer (score 2):

Vim para citar o [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads).

Anaconda é uma distribuição Python completamente livre (incluindo para uso comercial e redistribuição). Ele inclui mais de 195 dos [pacotes Python](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html) mais populares para a ciência, matemática, engenharia, análise de dados.

Essa distribuição vem com Spyder IDE, que lembra a interface do MATLAB.

Versões Python disponíveis: 2.7 e 3.4

Answer (score 1):

Na principal implementação da linguagem Python, o CPython, também conhecido por "implementação de referência", o interpretador é escrito em... adivinha?! C.

O CPython também é famoso por permitir fácil acesso a bibliotecas em C, seja quando há necessidade de otimizações de desempenho, ou servindo como linguagem de "cola" entre bibliotecas de baixo nível.

E então a comunidade usa muito este recurso... faltou desempenho? Desce para o C, e segue a vida. É assim com PIL, PyCrypto, simplejson, para citar algumas. Fantástico!

Quem programa em um ambiente onde o `gcc` está disponível fica fácil, não há nenhum transtorno. Mas quem precisa utilizar Windows sofre um bocado, pois CPython nesta plataforma é compilado oficialmente no MS Visual Studio.

Ao instalar um pacote que possui código em C, o processo de instalação tentará encontrar automaticamente um compilador. Se você não tem um compilador configurado, recebe um erro parecido com isso:

```
Error

Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

A solução é ou obter uma versão binária do pacote (com um instalador executável que você simplesmente clica em Next, Next, Finish!), ou configurar um compilador em sua máquina.

Se você pretende desenvolver em Python, eu **recomendo fortemente ter um compilador instalado**. As opções em Windows são: `Visual Studio` ou o `MinGW`. Como um compilador, o próprio **pip** se encarrega de solicitar o build a partir dos fontes, é muito mais fácil que procurar por um binário*.

Tenho um post sobre como instalar o Python no Windows e configurar um compilador: http://fernandomacedo.com/programacao/instalando-python-no-windows

- Alguns projetos dão trabalho para compilar por dependerem de outras bibliotecas que precisam estar no ambiente, mas não são a maioria, e você pode sempre recorrer a uma distribuição binária se o pip não funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de citar o [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), um gerenciador de pacotes para windows oferecendo uma experiência similar a dos gerênciadores de pacotes no linux, a instalação dele é simples basta copiar o comando abaixo e executa-lo no CMD

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

Depois disso basta utilizar o comando `choco search python` no CMD ou Powershell para listar os pacotes disponiveis. Bem como `choco install python` para instalar a versão 3 do python com os utilitários basicos.