# Python biblioteca Numpy

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, windows-7

Como que se instala uma biblioteca no python, usando Windows 7.
Eu tento baixar a Numpy e aparece no prompt:

```
libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python33\lib
libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python33\lib
.
.
.
Atlas libraries not found
Lapack libraries not found...
```

etc, não consigo baixar de jeito nenhum...

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra alternativa é usar o conda:

http://continuum.io/downloads

Eles também fornecem pacotes binários para várias plataformas. Nunca testei no Windows, mas deveria funcionar. No Mac foi o jeito mais fácil que encontrei pra instalar toda a suite de ciência sem dores de cabeça.

Answer (score 1):

O **numpy** necessita de algumas libs (dll) do sistema operacional com isso a LFD UCI, gerou alguns executaveis para Windows onde  simplifica a instalação, segue a baixo o mirror:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: Embora não esteja diretamente relacionado à pergunta, gostaria de acrescentar que esse mirror citado contém binários [pré-compilados para Windows] para uma grande variedade de bibliotecas Python. Isso é bastante útil, visto que com frequência é difícil [compilar no Windows a partir dos fontes](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1516/215)...